# understanding WinDbg output

Tags: c#, c++, exception, dll, windbg

I have a Winform application (C#) which imports some functions from dll.

Sometimes when running the application i get the following exception:

> System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. 
>   This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

I catch it in `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`.

So i tried to debug it with WinDbg. I was able to catch the exception and get the following output:

**!analyze -v**

```
FAULTING_IP: 
KERNEL32!SetErrorMode+14b
77e6c427 8a08            mov     cl,byte ptr [eax]

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 77e6c427 (KERNEL32!SetErrorMode+0x0000014b)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 00000000
   Parameter[1]: 087deadc
Attempt to read from address 087deadc

FAULTING_THREAD:  00000b1c

PROCESS_NAME:  App.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at "0x%08lx" referenced memory at "0x%08lx". The memory could not be "%s".

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at "0x%08lx" referenced memory at "0x%08lx". The memory could not be "%s".

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  00000000

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  087deadc

READ_ADDRESS:  087deadc 

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
KERNEL32!SetErrorMode+14b
77e6c427 8a08            mov     cl,byte ptr [eax]

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

MANAGED_STACK: !dumpstack -EE
OS Thread Id: 0xb1c (34)
Current frame: 
ChildEBP RetAddr  Caller,Callee

ADDITIONAL_DEBUG_TEXT:  Followup set based on attribute [UnloadedModule_Arch_AX] from Frame:[0] on thread:[b1c] ; Enable Pageheap/AutoVerifer

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  HEAP_CORRUPTION

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  HEAP_CORRUPTION

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_HEAP_CORRUPTION_INVALID_POINTER_READ

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 7a0aa797 to 77e6c427

STACK_TEXT:  
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
08bddc6c 7a0aa797 00000000 00000001 087deadc KERNEL32!SetErrorMode+0x14b
08bddd68 7c82a124 056306e8 08bddf9c 7c82a0b8 mscorwks!CorLaunchApplication+0x281f8
08bddd74 7c82a0b8 7c82a0fc 00000001 00000004 ntdll!RtlpAllocateFromHeapLookaside+0x13
08bddf9c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+0x1dd


STACK_COMMAND:  .ecxr ; ~~[b1c] ; .frame 0 ; ~34s ; kb

SYMBOL_NAME:  ure.dll!Unloaded

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: ure.dll

IMAGE_NAME:  ure.dll

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  750063

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  HEAP_CORRUPTION_c0000005_ure.dll!Unloaded

BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_FAULT_HEAP_CORRUPTION_INVALID_POINTER_READ_ure.dll!Unloaded

WATSON_STAGEONE_URL:  http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/App_exe/1_2009_403_12/49e707a9/KERNEL32_dll/5_2_3790_4062/46264680/c0000005/0002c427.htm?Retriage=1

Followup: MachineOwner
```

---

What does that mean? and what should i do with it?

Thanks in advance for any tips!!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `ure.dll` has been unloaded, and a call to <strike>NlsAnsiToUnicode</strike>MultiByteToWideChar() referring to it is failing.  You could run `.symfix` before `!analyze -v` to confirm that.

Is that the DLL you're importing?  If not, you have memory corruption.  Otherwise, the bug is probably in that DLL.  Are you using P/Invoke to import it?

---

Yup, the unloaded DLL information has been corrupted.  As you might guess, it's .NET's `culture.dll`, and Windbg is reading the 'cult' part of that as the timestamp and checksum.  Try restarting and doing the following:

```
.symfix
sxe ud
g
```

and when the breakpoint hits:

```
kb
```

(That's telling Windbg to run until the DLL is unloaded, and then dump the stack)

Run for a bit to let the module unload, and execute the following command.  Then let Windbg run until you get the exception, and do this command again to compare:

```
db ntdll!RtlpUnloadEventTrace
```

(That's the beginning of the unloaded module table, which is getting corrupted.)

Comment: Im not using this dll. I also do not have it on my computer. I have never heard of it before. No idea why is it trying to load it. However, it is unloaded:
Unloaded modules:
00000001 4333ab5a   ure.dll 
    Timestamp: Tue Mar 31 01:56:51 1970 (00750063)
    Checksum:  0074006C

Also when i execute !analyze -v, before giving me results it displays:
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for ure.dll
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for ure.dll

Help!

Comment: oh yes didnt realise that! At what point i need to run those commands? right after exception is cought? before analyze? after? before go? Thanks many!:)

Comment: before the exception is caught.

Comment: Mark, run the commands. And kb returns me the following:

ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
0dc9dc6c 7a0aa797 00000000 00000001 0522ea5c KERNEL32!SetErrorMode+0x14b
0dc9dd68 7c82a124 056306e8 0dc9df9c 7c82a0b8 mscorwks!CorLaunchApplication+0x281f8
0dc9dd74 7c82a0b8 7c82a0fc 00000001 00000004 ntdll!RtlpAllocateFromHeapLookaside+0x13
0dc9df9c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+0x1dd

Comment: however after i run  analyze - v it still tells me *** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for ure.dll
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for ure.dll

Comment: You can safely ignore that message - it can't verify "ure.dll" because it doesn't exist!

Comment: ok i got this:
0:040> db ntdll!RtlpUnloadEventTrace
7c8890c0  00 00 b9 77 00 80 00 00-00 00 00 00 c8 0a d7 45  ...w...........E
7c8890d0  4f c3 00 00 76 00 65 00-72 00 73 00 69 00 6f 00  O...v.e.r.s.i.o.
7c8890e0  6e 00 2e 00 64 00 6c 00-6c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  n...d.l.l.......
7c8890f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
7c889100  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

Comment: 7c889110  00 00 00 00 00 00 34 60-00 80 00 00 01 00 00 00  ......4`........
7c889120  59 ab 33 43 1f 33 01 00-63 00 75 00 6c 00 74 00  Y.3C.3..c.u.l.t.
7c889130  75 00 72 00 65 00 2e 00-64 00 6c 00 6c 00 00 00  u.r.e...d.l.l...

Comment: Hmm, I can't see any corruption there.  Has the exception happened yet?

Comment: Anya, you need to fix the system symbols! otherwise the stack information is misleading! run '.symfix+ c:\websymbols;.reload' and then rerun the analysis